# Responsive D3 Bar chart appending new <text> when resizing

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

trying to create responsive d3 chart. 
i created five function.

1. init();
2. updataScale();
3. updateBar();
4. updateLegends();
5. resize()

Under updateBar(), 
the problem with d3 text element  refer (plotGroupText.selectAll("text.grpTxt")) in code.

whenever i resize the window, i try to update the chart with their text values over lines of the graph. 
while updating the text over line, it creates more text nodes, instead of overwriting on same place. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mR16/8fc24g4y/2/

```js
(function() {
  console.clear();

  var chartContainer = d3.select("#chart");


  var layout = {
    w: 950,
    h: 906
  };


  var margin = {
    top: 50,
    left: 200,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 10
  }

  var data;
  var labels;
  var legendLabels;

  /////chart specific/////
  //height of chart//
  var maxPoint;
  var array;
  //svg element // 

  var svgElem;

  // group Elements
  var barGroup;
  var legendGroup;
  var plotGroupLine;
  var plotGroupOne;
  var plotGroupTwo;
  var plotGroupText;
  var plotGroupLabel;
  var legendIcon;
  var legendIconLabel;
  var scaleX;
  var scaleY;



  function init() {
    //get Data 
    data = getData();
    legendLabels = ["Aggregate Student Usage", "Aggregate ATI Recommended Usage"]
    labels = data.map(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    });

    //filter the data to determine the max of the array value 
    array = data.map(function(d, i) {
      return parseInt(i * 31 * 2)
    })
    maxpoint = d3.max(array) + 120;


    svgElem = chartContainer.append("svg")
    svgElem.attr("width", layout.w)
      .attr("height", layout.h)
      .attr("class", "svgElem")



    barGroup = svgElem.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    plotGroupLine = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupOne = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupTwo = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupText = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupLabel = barGroup.append("g");


    legendGroup = svgElem.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left * 1.5 + "," + margin.top / 2 + ")");

    legendIcon = legendGroup.append("g");
    legendIconLabel = legendGroup.append("g")



  }










  d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);

  function resize() {
    console.log("resize width");
    layout.w = parseInt(d3.select('#chart').style('width'), 10);
    console.log(layout.w)

    updataScale();
    updateBar();
  }


  function updataScale() {
    scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, layout.w - (margin.left + margin.right)])

    scaleY = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(labels).rangeBands([0, layout.h - margin.top - margin.bottom], 0.5)
  }

  function updateBar() {



    var lines = plotGroupLine.selectAll("line")
      .data(scaleX.ticks(10));

    lines.enter()
      .append("line")

    lines.exit()
      .remove();
    lines.attr("x1", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d)
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
        return scaleY.rangeBand() / 2 - 31
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d)
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
        return layout.h - scaleY.rangeBand() - margin.top + margin.bottom / 2

      })
      .attr("class", "lineStroke")



    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar one ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////


    var barOne = plotGroupOne.selectAll("rect.grpOne")
      .data(data);
    barOne.enter()
      .append("rect");

    barOne.attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 31 * 2
      })
      .attr("width", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d[1])
      })
      .attr("height", function(d, i) {
        return 31
      })
      .attr("class", "grpOne")

    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar two ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////

    var barTwo = plotGroupTwo.selectAll("rect.grpTwo")
      .data(data)
    barTwo.enter()
      .append("rect")

    barTwo
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 31 * 2
      })
      .attr("width", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d[2])
      })
      .attr("height", function(d, i) {
        return 31
      })
      .attr("class", "grpTwo")



    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar text ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////


    var barLineText = plotGroupText.selectAll("text.grpTxt")
      .data(scaleX.ticks(10))
    barLineText.enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d + "%"
      })

    barLineText.exit()
      .remove();

    barLineText.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d)
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return 32 / 2 - 31
      })
      .attr("dx", -5)
      .attr("dy", -5)
      .attr('font-size', "12")
      .attr("fill", "rgb(126,126,126)")




    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar label ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////

    var sideLabel = plotGroupLabel.selectAll("text.grpLabel")
      .data(data)
    sideLabel
      .enter()
      .append("text")
    sideLabel
      .text(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 2 * 31
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr('font-size', "12")
      .attr("fill", "rgb(126,126,126)")
      .attr("dx", -15)
      .attr("dy", 1)
      .call(wrapText, 160)
  }





  //////////////////////////////////
  ///////group the Plot area/////////
  //////////////////////////////////





  function wrapText(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
      var textEl = d3.select(this),
        words = textEl.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        linenumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = textEl.attr('y'),
        dx = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dx') || 0),
        dy = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dy') || 0),
        tspan = textEl.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');

      while (word = words.pop()) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(' '));
          line = [word];
          tspan = textEl.append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dx', dx).attr('dy', ++linenumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em').text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  }





  //////////////////////////////////
  /////// legend Icons  ///////////
  //////////////////////////////////

  var legendColors = ["rgb(91, 155, 213)", "rgb(164, 208, 233)"]


  function updateLegends() {
    legendIcon.selectAll("rect.legendIcon")
      .data(legendLabels)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i) * 200
      })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return legendColors[i]
      })


    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// legend labels ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////


    legendIconLabel.selectAll("text.legendLabel")
      .data(legendLabels)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(String)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i) * 200
      })
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr('font-size', "10")
      .attr("dx", 15)
      .attr("dy", 1)
      .on("click", function(d, i) {

        var elem = d3.select(this);
        var flagOne = false;
        var flagTwo = false;

        if (i == 0) {
          if (flagTwo == false) {
            if (elem.attr("text-decoration") == "none") {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "line-through")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpTwo").style("fill", "none");
              flagOne = true;
            } else {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "none")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpTwo").style("fill", " rgb(91, 155, 213)")
              flagOne = false;
            }
          }

        }
        if (i == 1) {
          if (flagOne == false) {
            if (elem.attr("text-decoration") == "none") {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "line-through")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpOne").style("fill", "none");
              flagTwo = true;
            } else {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "none")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpOne").style("fill", " rgb(164, 208, 233)")
              flagTwo = false;
            }
          }

        }

      })


  }


  init();
  updataScale();
  updateBar();
  updateLegends();

  function getData() {
    return [
      [
        "Adult Medical Surgical-(160minutes / 180minutes)",
        100,
        84
      ],
      [
        "Fundamentals-(1minutes / 60minutes)",
        100,
        2
      ],
      [
        "Getting Started with ATI-(1minutes / 28minutes)",
        100,
        4
      ],
      [
        "Leadership and Management-(124minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "NCLEX-(628minutes / 600minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "Pharm & Dosage Calculation-(242minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "1Adult Medical Surgical-(160minutes / 180minutes)",
        100,
        84
      ],
      [
        "1Fundamentals-(1minutes / 60minutes)",
        100,
        2
      ],
      [
        "1Getting Started with ATI-(1minutes / 28minutes)",
        100,
        4
      ],
      [
        "1Leadership and Management-(124minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "1NCLEX-(628minutes / 600minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "1Pharm & Dosage Calculation-(242minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ]
    ]


  }










})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```js
(function() {
    console.clear();

    var chartContainer = d3.select("#chart");


    var layout = {
        w: 950,
        h: 906
    };


    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        left: 200,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 10
    }

    var data;
    var labels;
    var legendLabels;

    /////chart specific/////
    //height of chart//
    var maxPoint;
    var array;
    //svg element // 

    var svgElem;

    // group Elements
    var barGroup;
    var legendGroup;
    var plotGroupLine;
    var plotGroupOne;
    var plotGroupTwo;
    var plotGroupText;
    var plotGroupLabel;
    var legendIcon;
    var legendIconLabel;
    var scaleX;
    var scaleY;



    function init() {
        //get Data 
        data = getData();
        legendLabels = ["Aggregate Student Usage", "Aggregate ATI Recommended Usage"]
        labels = data.map(function(d) {
            return d[0];
        });

        //filter the data to determine the max of the array value 
        array = data.map(function(d, i) {
            return parseInt(i * 31 * 2)
        })
        maxpoint = d3.max(array) + 120;


        svgElem = chartContainer.append("svg")
        svgElem.attr("width", layout.w)
            .attr("height", layout.h)
            .attr("class", "svgElem")



        barGroup = svgElem.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        plotGroupLine = barGroup.append("g");
        plotGroupOne = barGroup.append("g");
        plotGroupTwo = barGroup.append("g");
        plotGroupText = barGroup.append("g");
        plotGroupLabel = barGroup.append("g");


        legendGroup = svgElem.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left * 1.5 + "," + margin.top / 2 + ")");

        legendIcon = legendGroup.append("g");
        legendIconLabel = legendGroup.append("g")



    }




    d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);

    function resize() {
        console.log("resize width");
        layout.w = parseInt(d3.select('#chart').style('width'), 10);
        console.log(layout.w)

        updataScale();
        updateBar();
    }


    function updataScale() {
        scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100])
            .range([0, layout.w - (margin.left + margin.right)])

        scaleY = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(labels).rangeBands([0, layout.h - margin.top - margin.bottom], 0.5)
    }

    function updateBar() {



        var lines = plotGroupLine.selectAll("line")
            .data(scaleX.ticks(10));

        lines.enter()
            .append("line")

        lines.exit()
            .remove();
        lines.attr("x1", function(d, i) {
                return scaleX(d)
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
                return scaleY.rangeBand() / 2 - 31
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
                return scaleX(d)
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
                return layout.h - scaleY.rangeBand() - margin.top + margin.bottom / 2

            })
            .attr("class", "lineStroke")



        //////////////////////////////////
        /////// Plot bar one ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////


        var barOne = plotGroupOne.selectAll("rect.grpOne")
            .data(data);
        barOne.enter()
            .append("rect");

        barOne.attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                return i * 31 * 2
            })
            .attr("width", function(d, i) {
                return scaleX(d[1])
            })
            .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                return 31
            })
            .attr("class", "grpOne")

        //////////////////////////////////
        /////// Plot bar two ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////

        var barTwo = plotGroupTwo.selectAll("rect.grpTwo")
            .data(data)
        barTwo.enter()
            .append("rect")

        barTwo
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                return i * 31 * 2
            })
            .attr("width", function(d, i) {
                return scaleX(d[2])
            })
            .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                return 31
            })
            .attr("class", "grpTwo")



        //////////////////////////////////
        /////// Plot bar text ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////


        var barLineText = plotGroupText.selectAll("text.grpTxt")
            .data(scaleX.ticks(10))
        barLineText.enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d + "%"
            })

        barLineText.exit()
            .remove();

        barLineText.attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return scaleX(d)
            })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                return 32 / 2 - 31
            })
            .attr("dx", -5)
            .attr("dy", -5)
            .attr('font-size', "12")
            .attr("fill", "rgb(126,126,126)")




        //////////////////////////////////
        /////// Plot bar label ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////

        var sideLabel = plotGroupLabel.selectAll("text.grpLabel")
            .data(data)
        sideLabel
            .enter()
            .append("text")
        sideLabel
            .text(function(d) {
                return d[0];
            })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                return i * 2 * 31
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr('font-size', "12")
            .attr("fill", "rgb(126,126,126)")
            .attr("dx", -15)
            .attr("dy", 1)
            .call(wrapText, 160)
    }




    //////////////////////////////////
    ///////group the Plot area/////////
    //////////////////////////////////




    function wrapText(text, width) {
        text.each(function() {
            var textEl = d3.select(this),
                words = textEl.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                linenumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                y = textEl.attr('y'),
                dx = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dx') || 0),
                dy = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dy') || 0),
                tspan = textEl.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');

            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = textEl.append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dx', dx).attr('dy', ++linenumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em').text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }




    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// legend Icons  ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////

    var legendColors = ["rgb(91, 155, 213)", "rgb(164, 208, 233)"]


    function updateLegends() {
        legendIcon.selectAll("rect.legendIcon")
            .data(legendLabels)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return (i) * 200
            })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", 10)
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return legendColors[i]
            })


        //////////////////////////////////
        /////// legend labels ///////////
        //////////////////////////////////


        legendIconLabel.selectAll("text.legendLabel")
            .data(legendLabels)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(String)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return (i) * 200
            })
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr('font-size', "10")
            .attr("dx", 15)
            .attr("dy", 1)
            .on("click", function(d, i) {

                var elem = d3.select(this);
                var flagOne = false;
                var flagTwo = false;

                if (i == 0) {
                    if (flagTwo == false) {
                        if (elem.attr("text-decoration") == "none") {
                            elem.attr("text-decoration", "line-through")
                            svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpTwo").style("fill", "none");
                            flagOne = true;
                        } else {
                            elem.attr("text-decoration", "none")
                            svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpTwo").style("fill", " rgb(91, 155, 213)")
                            flagOne = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    if (flagOne == false) {
                        if (elem.attr("text-decoration") == "none") {
                            elem.attr("text-decoration", "line-through")
                            svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpOne").style("fill", "none");
                            flagTwo = true;
                        } else {
                            elem.attr("text-decoration", "none")
                            svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpOne").style("fill", " rgb(164, 208, 233)")
                            flagTwo = false;
                        }
                    }

                }

            })


    }


    init();
    updataScale();
    updateBar();
    updateLegends();

    function getData() {
        return [
            [
                "Adult Medical Surgical-(160minutes / 180minutes)",
                100,
                84
            ],
            [
                "Fundamentals-(1minutes / 60minutes)",
                100,
                2
            ],
            [
                "Getting Started with ATI-(1minutes / 28minutes)",
                100,
                4
            ],
            [
                "Leadership and Management-(124minutes / 120minutes)",
                100,
                100
            ],
            [
                "NCLEX-(628minutes / 600minutes)",
                100,
                100
            ],
            [
                "Pharm & Dosage Calculation-(242minutes / 120minutes)",
                100,
                100
            ],
            [
                "1Adult Medical Surgical-(160minutes / 180minutes)",
                100,
                84
            ],
            [
                "1Fundamentals-(1minutes / 60minutes)",
                100,
                2
            ],
            [
                "1Getting Started with ATI-(1minutes / 28minutes)",
                100,
                4
            ],
            [
                "1Leadership and Management-(124minutes / 120minutes)",
                100,
                100
            ],
            [
                "1NCLEX-(628minutes / 600minutes)",
                100,
                100
            ],
            [
                "1Pharm & Dosage Calculation-(242minutes / 120minutes)",
                100,
                100
            ]
        ]


    }




})()
```

```css
.svgElem{
  border: 1px solid 
}

.grpOne{
 fill: rgb(164, 208, 233);
}

.grpTwo{
fill: rgb(91, 155, 213)
}

.lineStroke{
  stroke:#ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

I represent in picture

problem 
[image]
how i want 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're selecting by class:

```
 var barLineText = plotGroupText.selectAll("text.grpTxt")
```

You have to set the same class to your text elements:

```
.attr("class", "grpTxt")
```

Otherwise, you'll have non-empty enter selections. Do the same for `.grpLabel`.

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68Lp0L4x/

Or check the snippet:

```js
(function() {
  console.clear();

  var chartContainer = d3.select("#chart");


  var layout = {
    w: 950,
    h: 906
  };


  var margin = {
    top: 50,
    left: 200,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 10
  }

  var data;
  var labels;
  var legendLabels;

  /////chart specific/////
  //height of chart//
  var maxPoint;
  var array;
  //svg element // 

  var svgElem;

  // group Elements
  var barGroup;
  var legendGroup;
  var plotGroupLine;
  var plotGroupOne;
  var plotGroupTwo;
  var plotGroupText;
  var plotGroupLabel;
  var legendIcon;
  var legendIconLabel;
  var scaleX;
  var scaleY;



  function init() {
    //get Data 
    data = getData();
    legendLabels = ["Aggregate Student Usage", "Aggregate ATI Recommended Usage"]
    labels = data.map(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    });

    //filter the data to determine the max of the array value 
    array = data.map(function(d, i) {
      return parseInt(i * 31 * 2)
    })
    maxpoint = d3.max(array) + 120;


    svgElem = chartContainer.append("svg")
    svgElem.attr("width", layout.w)
      .attr("height", layout.h)
      .attr("class", "svgElem")



    barGroup = svgElem.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    plotGroupLine = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupOne = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupTwo = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupText = barGroup.append("g");
    plotGroupLabel = barGroup.append("g");


    legendGroup = svgElem.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left * 1.5 + "," + margin.top / 2 + ")");

    legendIcon = legendGroup.append("g");
    legendIconLabel = legendGroup.append("g")



  }










  d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);

  function resize() {
    console.log("resize width");
    layout.w = parseInt(d3.select('#chart').style('width'), 10);
    console.log(layout.w)

    updataScale();
    updateBar();
  }


  function updataScale() {
    scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, layout.w - (margin.left + margin.right)])

    scaleY = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(labels).rangeBands([0, layout.h - margin.top - margin.bottom], 0.5)
  }

  function updateBar() {



    var lines = plotGroupLine.selectAll("line")
      .data(scaleX.ticks(10));

    lines.enter()
      .append("line")

    lines.exit()
      .remove();
    lines.attr("x1", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d)
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
        return scaleY.rangeBand() / 2 - 31
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d)
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
        return layout.h - scaleY.rangeBand() - margin.top + margin.bottom / 2

      })
      .attr("class", "lineStroke")



    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar one ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////


    var barOne = plotGroupOne.selectAll("rect.grpOne")
      .data(data);
    barOne.enter()
      .append("rect");

    barOne.attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 31 * 2
      })
      .attr("width", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d[1])
      })
      .attr("height", function(d, i) {
        return 31
      })
      .attr("class", "grpOne")

    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar two ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////

    var barTwo = plotGroupTwo.selectAll("rect.grpTwo")
      .data(data)
    barTwo.enter()
      .append("rect")

    barTwo
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 31 * 2
      })
      .attr("width", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d[2])
      })
      .attr("height", function(d, i) {
        return 31
      })
      .attr("class", "grpTwo")



    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar text ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////


    var barLineText = plotGroupText.selectAll("text.grpTxt")
      .data(scaleX.ticks(10))
    barLineText.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "grpTxt")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d + "%"
      })

    barLineText.exit()
      .remove();

    barLineText.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return scaleX(d)
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return 32 / 2 - 31
      })
      .attr("dx", -5)
      .attr("dy", -5)
      .attr('font-size', "12")
      .attr("fill", "rgb(126,126,126)")




    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// Plot bar label ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////

    var sideLabel = plotGroupLabel.selectAll("text.grpLabel")
      .data(data)
    sideLabel
      .enter()
      .append("text")
    sideLabel
      .text(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })
      .attr("class", "grpLabel")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 2 * 31
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr('font-size', "12")
      .attr("fill", "rgb(126,126,126)")
      .attr("dx", -15)
      .attr("dy", 1)
      .call(wrapText, 160)
  }





  //////////////////////////////////
  ///////group the Plot area/////////
  //////////////////////////////////





  function wrapText(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
      var textEl = d3.select(this),
        words = textEl.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        linenumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = textEl.attr('y'),
        dx = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dx') || 0),
        dy = parseFloat(textEl.attr('dy') || 0),
        tspan = textEl.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');

      while (word = words.pop()) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(' '));
          line = [word];
          tspan = textEl.append('tspan').attr('x', 0).attr('y', y).attr('dx', dx).attr('dy', ++linenumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em').text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  }





  //////////////////////////////////
  /////// legend Icons  ///////////
  //////////////////////////////////

  var legendColors = ["rgb(91, 155, 213)", "rgb(164, 208, 233)"]


  function updateLegends() {
    legendIcon.selectAll("rect.legendIcon")
      .data(legendLabels)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i) * 200
      })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return legendColors[i]
      })


    //////////////////////////////////
    /////// legend labels ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////


    legendIconLabel.selectAll("text.legendLabel")
      .data(legendLabels)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(String)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return (i) * 200
      })
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr('font-size', "10")
      .attr("dx", 15)
      .attr("dy", 1)
      .on("click", function(d, i) {

        var elem = d3.select(this);
        var flagOne = false;
        var flagTwo = false;

        if (i == 0) {
          if (flagTwo == false) {
            if (elem.attr("text-decoration") == "none") {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "line-through")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpTwo").style("fill", "none");
              flagOne = true;
            } else {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "none")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpTwo").style("fill", " rgb(91, 155, 213)")
              flagOne = false;
            }
          }

        }
        if (i == 1) {
          if (flagOne == false) {
            if (elem.attr("text-decoration") == "none") {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "line-through")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpOne").style("fill", "none");
              flagTwo = true;
            } else {
              elem.attr("text-decoration", "none")
              svgElem.selectAll("rect.grpOne").style("fill", " rgb(164, 208, 233)")
              flagTwo = false;
            }
          }

        }

      })


  }


  init();
  updataScale();
  updateBar();
  updateLegends();

  function getData() {
    return [
      [
        "Adult Medical Surgical-(160minutes / 180minutes)",
        100,
        84
      ],
      [
        "Fundamentals-(1minutes / 60minutes)",
        100,
        2
      ],
      [
        "Getting Started with ATI-(1minutes / 28minutes)",
        100,
        4
      ],
      [
        "Leadership and Management-(124minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "NCLEX-(628minutes / 600minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "Pharm & Dosage Calculation-(242minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "1Adult Medical Surgical-(160minutes / 180minutes)",
        100,
        84
      ],
      [
        "1Fundamentals-(1minutes / 60minutes)",
        100,
        2
      ],
      [
        "1Getting Started with ATI-(1minutes / 28minutes)",
        100,
        4
      ],
      [
        "1Leadership and Management-(124minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "1NCLEX-(628minutes / 600minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ],
      [
        "1Pharm & Dosage Calculation-(242minutes / 120minutes)",
        100,
        100
      ]
    ]


  }










})()
```

```css
.svgElem {
  border: 1px solid
}

.grpOne {
  fill: rgb(164, 208, 233);
}

.grpTwo {
  fill: rgb(91, 155, 213)
}

.lineStroke {
  stroke: #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```